# Use of Ajax to refresh Struts2 datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts2

I have created a datatable in Struts2 and also have a feature of adding a record into this table by some action. After the record is inserted we are refreshing the page to get the table refreshed.
I had tried to use Ajax for this purpose and send the new values we have inserted to the Action class by request parameter and in the response we are getting the table refreshed.

My Ajax function is:

```
function reloadTable(){

var ajaxRequest;
    try {
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
                    catch (e) 
                {
                try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
                catch (e) 
                {
                                alert("Your browser has no AJAX Support!");
                    return false;
                }
        }
        }
       var elem1 = document.getElementById('host0');
       var elem2 = document.getElementById('ip0');
       var elemTable = document.getElementById('hostTable');
       //alert(indexSelected);
       //alert(document.getElementById(elem).options[indexSelected].value); 
    var url = "insertTable.action";
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        try 
        {
                if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                        var res = ajaxRequest.responseText;
                        if (res)
                        {
                                //alert("hi"+res.greeting);
                                document.getElementById("hostTable").innerHTML = res;
                                //adjustTable();
                        }
                }
        } 
        catch (e) 
        {

        }
    };
    //alert(selectedCountry);
    ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var hostName = elem1.value;
    var ipAddress = elem2.value;
    //alert("AJAX CALL"+elem1.value+elem2.value);   
    //ajaxRequest.send("hostName="+elem1.value+"&ipAddress="+elem2.value);
    ajaxRequest.send("hostName="+hostName+"&ipAddress="+ipAddress);
    //ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Content in my Struts.xml is:

```
<action name="insertTable" method="insertNewData" class="action.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Method in my action class:

```
public String insertNewData(){
    populateList();
    System.out.println("Hi"+getHostName()+getIpAddress());
    userNameList.add(new UserType(hostName,ipAddress));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Now I want the list populated in the actionClass method to be reflected in the table by this Ajax call. In this method I am appending the value that I am sending through parameter in the Ajax method. I can fetch the new values in the action class method but while sending the response the whole page is displayed in place of the table.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

> After the record is inserted we are refreshing the page to get the
>   table refreshed.

Is it like you don't want to refresh the whole page for that. In that case I suggest you to use [Struts2 Jquery Plugin](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=struts2%20jquery%20grid%20plugin&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/&ei=LqkET5z9DomJrAeLoJXSDw&usg=AFQjCNFgY6KtGJr_7jmyDla6N6NQ5qantQ). [Grid showcase](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=struts2%20jquery%20grid%20plugin&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-grid-showcase/&ei=LqkET5z9DomJrAeLoJXSDw&usg=AFQjCNEqZefPJ43g8SqcDnuMvCC2zfUj9w) does exactly what you want to do.
For more examples you can visit [Online Examples](http://www.onlinexamples.com/searchaction.action?idlabels=21&label=struts2jquery) and can request can example if you want  something more specific.